# Speeding up WarpedVRT in rasterio (change CRS + resample)

Tags: gdal, rasterio, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

Given a source GeoTIFF of some unknown resolution (better than the target), what is the quickest way to re-project it in-memory to the desired GSD? Masking in the input data should be preserved.

Typically I do this at the file level using `gdal_translate` (to a VRT with the desired CRS) and then `gdalwarp` (to the desired GSD) and I generate the commands in code. This is reasonably fast, but it seems like dealing with masking is not trivial e.g. inferring whether the mask is internal, if a mask sidecar is provided, etc.

I've tried the following code which seems to do what I want in that the output image is the right shape/extent, but it's very slow:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
import affine
import time

target_gsd = 0.1

with rasterio.Env(GDAL_NUM_THREADS="ALL_CPUS"):
    with rasterio.open(image_path) as src:

        x_scale = src.res[1] / target_gsd
        y_scale = src.res[0] / target_gsd
    
        dst_height = int( src.height * y_scale)
        dst_width  = int( src.width * x_scale)
    
        left, bottom, right, top = transform_bounds(src.crs.to_epsg(), 3395, *src.bounds)
        dst_transform = affine.Affine(target_gsd, 0.0, left,
                          0.0, -target_gsd, top)

        vrt_options = {
            'resampling': Resampling.bilinear,
            'crs': "EPSG:3395",
            'transform': dst_transform,
            'height': dst_height,
            'width': dst_width
        }

        tstart = time.time()
    
        with rasterio.vrt.WarpedVRT(src, **vrt_options) as vrt:
            masks = vrt.read_masks()
            data = vrt.read()
        tend = time.time()
```

It'd be useful to know why this takes so long, because in theory all that needs to happen underneath is a resize by some factor, e.g. x1/10 and this is pretty quick with e.g. OpenCV:

```
import cv2
tstart = time.time()
with rasterio.open(image_path) as src:
    
    scale_fac = src.res[0]/target_gsd
    data = src.read()
    data_resize = cv2.resize(np.transpose(data,(1,2,0)), dsize=None, fx=scale_fac, fy=scale_fac)
tend = time.time()
```

which takes around 12 seconds for my example (30k x 20k ish). The VRT example takes at around 21s without reading the mask. If the mask is read as well, then it takes 83s. Neither of these solutions use more than a single core when I inspect via htop, while gdalwarp can use `-multi` / `ALL_CPUS` and I get full utilisation.

Comment: Do you have any update on this ? I have similar needs